# Changing frozen dataclass to support dynamic fields

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a Python dataclass that looks like

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class BaseDataclass:
    immutable_arg_1 = field1
    immutable_arg_2 = field2
```

It's preferrable to not have to change the base class much since it's currently used in a bunch of places in the codebase it is in, but now there's a use-case for where having a dataclass that's dynamically constructed is much more convenitant. Is there any way of constructing a new dataclass that extends this with some dynamically chosen arguments (the subclass itself may be dynamically defined).

```
def dataclass_factory(kwargs: Dict) -> BaseDataclass:
    @dataclass(frozen=True)
    class DerivedDataclass(BaseDataclass):
        **kwargs  # not valid python syntax here

    return DerivedDataclass(**kwargs)
```

so that I can do something like

```
new_dataclass = dataclass_factory({'immutable_arg_3': field3, 'immutable_arg_4': field4})
```

Comment: have you tried https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass ?

Comment: even soething like `class DerivedClass(BaseClass): pass` then `DerivedClass.__annotations__ = kwargs`, then finally, `return dataclass(frozen=True)(DerivedClass)`